# Special case coefficient sum in multinomial equation

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients

I need to find the sum of coefficients of $x^{c}$ in the general equation

$(1+x)^{a_1}(1+x^2)^{a_2}...(1+x^m)^{a_m}$, where $c$ is a multiple of $m+1$.

For example in
$(1+x)^2(1+x^2)$ the coefficient of $x^0$ plus the coefficient of $x^3$ is $3$.

Comment: Are asking for the sum of coefficients x^c where c is a divisor of m+1? Please note that 3 is a multiple of (2+1), but zero isn't. So, in your example, the multiples of (2+1) are 3,6,9,.. while the divisors are 1 and 3. Which is it?

Comment: its like c mod (m+1) =0 and c>=0

Comment: Since the values of the exponents a_k are free parameters, this problem is easy to calculate with a computer algebra system for any given set of the a_k, but I would be surprised if a combinatorial solution is available.